# What is the benefit/purpose of the [editor] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

From my understanding, a tag is mostly used to categorize questions to avoid having to include important information in the question title, and also to allow those interested in a given topic to browse questions on the tag topic in a convenient manner.

Some tags have many many followers. The [editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/editor) tag has 48 followers, yet 3.6k questions (compared to say 6.7k followers and 14.3k questions for [vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim)).

I also note some discussion in the comments to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/235839/3063884) indicating that the tag isn't very useful.

Apart from perhaps indicating to a user unfamiliar with a given type of editor that it is indeed an editor, I don't see this tag as very useful. What's its benefit/purpose? (And should it be removed?)

Comment: A tag being "not very useful" isn't exactly motivation to go spend a bunch of effort trying to remove it from thousands of questions.  If it were actively harmful, as many tags are, then sure.  The tag is sensible as a tag, just not that useful in practice.  Seems like the best thing to do is ignore it.

Comment: An alternative view is that it's just noise - a tag for a tag's sake. I'm not actively advocating removing it, rather trying to understand its purpose.

Comment: That is of course what the tag wiki is there for; to explain the tag's purpose.

Comment: Purpose in terms of benefit -- i.e. why use the tag? What benefit does it provide?

Comment: It is a *contextual* tag.  It makes it very likely that users that answered questions before about, say, the editor in a specific IDE are going to see that question on their personalized front page.  After the "main" tag(s) are filtered by their preferences.

Comment: Most editors have their own tags, e.g: [intellij-idea]; [android-studio]; [visual-studio-2013]; [vim] - and thus are useful, but [editor] is about as plain-vanilla generic as a tag can get.

Comment: Burninate this tag. It is extremely broad and fails to usefully categorize questions.